# Column-wise UNION, or ordering two columns of SELECT/JOIN query with distinct orderings

Tags: mysql, select, order-by

I have a table, `employee`, and one of the columns is `last_name`, which stores strings.

Using a SELECT query, I am trying to get the `last_name` column, ordered alphabetically, as one column, and another column, again `last_name`, this time ordered in reverse alphabetical order.

The desired result looks something like

```
+-----------------+----------------+
| last name       | last name      |
+-----------------+----------------+
|  Apple          | Xylophone      |
+-----------------+----------------+
```

I have tried

```
SELECT a.last_name, b.last_name
FROM employee A
LEFT JOIN employee B
ON a.last_name = b.last_name
ORDER BY a.last_name, b.last_name DESC;
```

Which, of course, doesn't work, because it orders both columns by last_name in alphabetical order, and doesn't even get to the other order condition because the syntax specifies that condition `n` is only used if some rows are equal under condition `n-1`.

In my head, I see this as something like

```
SELECT last_name 
FROM employee 
ORDER BY last_name;
```

and

```
SELECT last_name 
FROM employee 
ORDER BY last_name DESC;
```

But I don't know how to combine the two. When I UNION these two queries, I get the right data, but it's in the form of two columns concatenated into one, when I need both columns kept distinct.

I tried using a JOIN, here, which was a total shot in the dark as I've never seen syntax like this:

```
(SELECT a.last_name 
FROM employee a 
ORDER BY a.last_name 
LIMIT 1) 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT b.last_name 
FROM employee b 
ORDER BY b.last_name DESC 
LIMIT 1) 
ON a.last_name = b.last_name;
```

and of course that didn't work either. So I have no clue on how to proceed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data you are using?  Have you tried `SELECT MIN(Last_Name), MAX(Last_Name) FROM employee`?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to merge all last_names? Please share a sample data, you can use something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/uUrg--Ep

Comment: @bbaird That is actually exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

One way to solve this is using `ROW_NUMBER()` function, available in MySQL version 8.0. We can get row numbers with the different orders in two subqueries (derived tables or CTEs) and then join them.

Tested in [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/K0Xy8lyM):

```
WITH 
  a AS
  ( SELECT 
        last_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY last_name) AS rn
    FROM employee 
  ),
  d AS
  ( SELECT 
        last_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY last_name DESC) AS rn
    FROM employee 
)
SELECT
    a.last_name AS last_name_a,
    d.last_name AS last_name_d
FROM a JOIN d USING (rn) ;
```